# Reading IIS trace files concerning ASP.NET problems

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure-web-app-service

There is one common error condition that I'm still in the dark about how I track down the cause.

I'm sometimes encounter 403 results, "You do not have permission to view this directory or page".

The actual problem is, however, not that I don't have permission to view the directory but that ASP.NET isn't serving the page. The DirectoryListingModule is then giving me the error that gets displayed.

I know I can activate request tracing which gives me a really long file that contains information about how IIS processes the request.

Yet, I'm not sure what to make of it.

I've [linked the trace file in question](https://permanent-small-hostings.azurewebsites.net/stackoverflow/tracefile.xml), as it's quite large. Any ideas anybody?

Answer (score 0):

According to your request trace, I assumed that you configured your custom domain and point to `visbricks-staging.azurewebsites.net`. Based on your trace file, this error occurs when you accessing the root path of your website, and it seems that there is no default page in your website, then the `DirectoryListingModule` would try to list the contents of your root directory, but the Directory Browsing feature is disabled by default, then you would retrieve HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden as follows:

[image]

You could try to set the default document to narrow this issue, and you could do it on azure portal [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/change-default-page-in-azure-website1) or configure it in your web.config [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rakkimk/2007/05/25/iis7-how-to-configure-the-default-document-of-the-website-in-its-web-config/).

Comment: I'm doing MVC, that's why I don't have a default document. I think this works by IIS asking ASP.NET if it wants to serve the request, and when the ASP.NET app says no, it will continue to other handlers, such as the directory listing handler. But I wonder in which line you can actually see this "ASP.NET says 'not me'".

Comment: I just read the request trace and provided my idea for this issue. For mvc application,  have you tried to access e.g. `/home/index` for test? As you said that you encounter the 403.14 sometimes, have you configured something or deploy new features to your azure web app before this issue happens?